# Jquery ajax não funciona em dispositivo mobile só funciona em versão desktop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

To na seguinte situação, meu formulário de login está funcionando perfeitamente em versão desktop, fui testar no android e no ios ele não funciona e não da nem um erro no console... apenas fica aguardando a resposta da api.. segue meu arquivo javascript

```
$(function() {

    $("#login-form").validate({

        rules : {
            email : {
                required : true,
                email : true
            },
            password : {
                required : true,
                minlength : 0,
                maxlength : 20
            }
        },

        messages : {
            email : {
                required : 'E-mail do game',
                email : 'E-mail do gmae não e valido'
            },
            password : {
                required : 'Senha do game'
            }
        },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    });

    function submitForm()
    {
        var data = $("#login-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({

            type : 'POST', 
            url  : 'http://localhost/api.game/api/auth',
            data : data,

            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#error").fadeOut();
                $("#btn-login").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; Aguarde logando.');
            },

            success :  function(response) {

                if(response.status === true){
                    $("#btn-login").html('<img src="../img/rolling.gif" /> &nbsp; Logado você vai ser redirecionado');

                    setTimeout(function(){location.href=response.redirect} , 2000);
                }
                else{
                    $("#error").fadeIn(100, function(){
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response.msg+' !</div>');
                        $("#btn-login").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Entrar');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }


});
```

alguém ai já passou por esse problema ??? não está retornando nem um erro no console.

Comment: Preciso ver seu HTML.

Comment: Olá, não retornar um erro no console não significa que está tudo correto, você está enviando informação e recebendo via ajax, porem ele gera resposta, se faz necessário você verificar o que é recebido na api e o que  está sendo enviado como retorno ao ajax, veja item por item bem detalhado.